# Length mismatch error when using set_index using dask Series on dask DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dask

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.array as dka
import dask.dataframe as dkf

vals = np.arange(200).reshape(20,10)
vals = dka.from_array(vals)
columns = [f"col_{i}" for i in range(10)]

ser = pd.Series(range(20), index=np.arange(20)+100, name='idx')

ddf = dkf.from_dask_array(vals, columns=columns)
dks = dkf.from_pandas(ser, npartitions=ddf.npartitions)

ddf.set_index(dks, sorted=True).compute()
-----------------
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 19 rows, received array of length 0
```

I'm confused about this error, `dks` has 20 elements, why does `dask` complain it has length 0? and why does it expect 19 rows when the `ddf` has 20 rows?

Comment: i tried your code without problems (python 3.10, pandas 1.3.5, numpy 1.22.1dask 2022.4.0 on manjaro Linux), maybe there is a bug in an older version

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I'm using numpy 1.21.4, dask 2021.11.2, pd 1.3.4 so that might be the reason of what looks like a bug